# Better way to get data of row from data grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, grid, telerik-grid

I am using the client API to get the row data of a Telerik MVC grid, but it is very inefficient especially when this is in a loop for hundreds of rows:

```
var grid = row.closest("div.t-grid").data("tGrid");
var rowIndex = row[0].rowIndex;
var rowData = grid.data[rowIndex];
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just access the model and maybe get my row from there. I am not sure what you are trying to do, but you can make the grid row clickable  and handle it that way.

Either way, I think we need more information to be able to help you better.